# MySQL query showing multiple results

Tags: mysql, join, search, sql-like

I'm building a search page where a form will pass variables to a SQL query.  If I input any search parameter, I get the results I want, unless I leave either the author or the subject search blank, I will get multiple results if there are multiple authors and/or subjects associated with the results.  Most of my records have multiple authors or multiple subjects.

The basic problem is that if there is one record with 2 authors and 3 associated subjects, then I get 6 results.

WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE:  I am trying to modify the query so that I only receive one record (record_ID is unique), even if there are multiple authors or multiple subjects.

The 2 JOINS in the query I am having problems with are to pull the author and subject.  For example, for to get the author, I use this join (the subject JOIN is almost identical) and the variable $fauthor is passed in from php:

```
SELECT la.author, la.author_ID, ra.record_ID
FROM lib_author AS la
JOIN record_author AS ra ON la.author_ID = ra.author_ID
JOIN lib_record AS lr ON ra.record_ID = lr.record_ID
WHERE la.author LIKE '%$fauthor%'
```

The associated tables are lib_author [author_ID, author], lib_record [record_ID, ...], and record_author [record_ID, author_ID]

Here is the complete query:

```
select a.record_ID, a.year, n.title, y.author, y.author_ID, j.journal, pox.publisher, lox.language, a.volume, a.issue, a.pages, a.abstract, s.subject
   FROM lib_record AS a  
   JOIN lib_title as n on n.title_ID = a.title_ID
   JOIN (SELECT la.author, la.author_ID, ra.record_ID
       FROM lib_author AS la
       JOIN record_author AS ra ON la.author_ID = ra.author_ID
       JOIN lib_record AS lr ON ra.record_ID = lr.record_ID
            WHERE la.author LIKE '%$fauthor%') AS y 
   JOIN (SELECT ls.subject, ls.subject_ID, rs.record_ID 
        FROM lib_subject AS ls
        JOIN record_subject AS rs ON ls.subject_ID = rs.subject_ID
        JOIN lib_record AS lr ON rs.record_ID = lr.record_ID
            WHERE ls.subject LIKE '%$fsubject%') AS s
   JOIN lib_journal AS j on j.journal_ID = a.journal_ID
   JOIN lib_publisher pox ON a.publisher_ID = pox.publisher_ID
   JOIN lib_language lox ON a.language_ID = lox.language_ID
   WHERE y.record_ID = a.record_ID 
   AND s.record_ID = a.record_ID
   AND n.title LIKE '%$ftitle%'
   AND j.journal LIKE '%$fjournal%'
```

I hope someone has some insight.  Thanks

Comment: If you have multiple authors, listed, what's the intended outcome? Just pick the first one, or grab a comma-separated list?

Comment: The intended outcome is a single row which shows data associated with the record.  The row is an href that will send the user to a card catalog with all of the information displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just want to group the results by record_ID. Using your simpler query:

```
SELECT la.author, la.author_ID, ra.record_ID
  FROM lib_author AS la
  JOIN record_author AS ra ON la.author_ID = ra.author_ID
  JOIN lib_record AS lr ON ra.record_ID = lr.record_ID
  WHERE la.author LIKE '%$fauthor%'
  GROUP BY ra.record_ID
```

this will grab the *last* entry for la.*. If you want a comma-separated list of authors, you could use group_concat().

Comment: Hi @Doug Kress, thanks for your response.  Grouping by *.record_ID does not work.  The example I gave above in the write-up states that if one record has 2 authors and 3 subjects I will get 2 x 3 results or 6 rows, each with the same record_ID

Comment: If you `GROUP BY` record_ID, that will collapse all 6 records into a single record (somewhat ambiguously selecting the author/author_ID, unless you use an `ORDER_BY` or something as well). Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually no.  The GROUP BY works!  Just not where you thought. After "AND j.journal LIKE '%$fjournal%'" at the end of the query, I put in the following "GROUP BY a.record_ID" and get exactly what I was looking for.  So simple it was hard to see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final query with GROUP BY added at the end and GROUP_CONCAT added to both the author and subject JOINS to show complete data sets.  Thanks to @Doug Kress for helping out!  I'm just a volunteer webmaster:

```
select a.record_ID, a.year, n.title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT y.author SEPARATOR '; ') AS author, y.author_ID, j.journal, pox.publisher, lox.language, a.volume, a.issue, a.pages, a.abstract, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.subject SEPARATOR '; ') AS subject
   FROM lib_record AS a  
   JOIN lib_title as n on n.title_ID = a.title_ID
   JOIN (SELECT la.author, la.author_ID, ra.record_ID
       FROM lib_author AS la
       JOIN record_author AS ra ON la.author_ID = ra.author_ID
       JOIN lib_record AS lr ON ra.record_ID = lr.record_ID
            WHERE la.author LIKE '%$fauthor%') AS y 
   JOIN (SELECT ls.subject, ls.subject_ID, rs.record_ID 
        FROM lib_subject AS ls
        JOIN record_subject AS rs ON ls.subject_ID = rs.subject_ID
        JOIN lib_record AS lr ON rs.record_ID = lr.record_ID
            WHERE ls.subject LIKE '%$fsubject%') AS s
   JOIN lib_journal AS j on j.journal_ID = a.journal_ID
   JOIN lib_publisher pox ON a.publisher_ID = pox.publisher_ID
   JOIN lib_language lox ON a.language_ID = lox.language_ID
   WHERE y.record_ID = a.record_ID 
   AND s.record_ID = a.record_ID
   AND n.title LIKE '%$ftitle%'
   AND j.journal LIKE '%$fjournal%' 
   GROUP BY a.record_ID
```